# How do you create two separate Register pages?

Tags: php, users, user-registration

I am looking for a way to make two separate register pages. One will automatically assign users up as a **subscriber**, while the other will sign them up as a **contributor**.

The only thing I have thought of so far is to duplicate the *register_new_user* function in the wp-login.php file and customize it a bit.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically all you need to do is add an hidden field named role and set the value to whatever role you want on the register form.

```
add_action('register_form','show_role_field');
function show_role_field(){ ?>
<input id="role" type="hidden" tabindex="20" size="25" value= "<?php if (isset($_GET['role'])){echo $_GET['role'];} ?>"  name="role"/>
    <?php
}
```

Next thing is to register that role when the user has submitted the registration form.

```
add_action('user_register', 'register_role');

function register_role($user_id, $password="", $meta=array()) {

   $userdata = array();
   $userdata['ID'] = $user_id;
   $userdata['role'] = $_POST['role'];

   //only allow if user role is my_role

   if ($userdata['role'] == "my_role"){
      wp_update_user($userdata);
   }
}
```

Now all that is left to do is direct the user to the register url with the role that you want as a query var, for example

```
http://example.com/wp-login.php?action=register&role=my_role
```

You can read more http://www.jasarwebsolutions.com/2010/06/27/how-to-change-a-users-role-on-the-wordpress-registration-form/
And i would suggest that you check to validate the role is allowed to register before saving it so you wont get a few new admins in your site.